# Gradle - throw exception if project still has SNAPSHOT dependencies

Tags: java, .net, gradle, groovy

I want to **fail** the gradle build if the current project still has **snapshot** dependencies.

My code so far only looks for java dependencies, missing the .NET ones so it only works for java projects. I want to make it work for all projects.

```
def addSnapshotCheckingTask(Project project) {
    project.tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { compileJava ->
        project.tasks.create(compileJava.name + 'SnapshotChecking', {
            onlyIf {
                project.ext.isRelease || project.ext.commitVersion != null
            }
            compileJava.dependsOn it
            doLast {
                def snapshots = compileJava.classpath
                        .filter { project.ext.isRelease || !(it.path ==~ /(?i)${project.rootProject.projectDir.toString().replace('\\', '\\\\')}.*build.libs.*/) }
                        .filter { it.path =~ /(?i)-SNAPSHOT/  }
                        .collect { it.name }
                        .unique()
                if (!snapshots.isEmpty()) {
                    throw new GradleException("Please get rid of snapshots for following dependencies before releasing $snapshots")
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I need some help in generifying this snippet to be applicable to all types of dependencies(not just java)

Thanks!

L.E. Could something like this work?
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-can-i-check-for-snapshot-dependencies-and-throw-an-exception-if-some-where-found/4064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
Collection<ResolvedArtifact> snapshotArtifacts = project.configurations*.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.filter { it.moduleVersion.id.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT') }
if (!snapshotArtifacts.empty) {
   // throw exception
}
```

See 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html#getResolvedConfiguration--
https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ResolvedConfiguration.html#getResolvedArtifacts--

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, using that snippet I get this:  Resolving configuration 'apiElements' directly is not allowed

Comment: I'm guessing that the `apiElements` configuration dependsOn another task. To test the theory you could make the *SnapshotChecking task(s) `dependsOn` every other task. You could also try adding `inputs.files project.configurations` to your task declaration and gradle might wire the DAG for you

Comment: I've just added the check if(it.isCanBeResolved()) to exclude unresolvable configurations. Seems this is a breaking change introduced in gradle 4.0 or something like that

Answer (score 3):

So I got it working by tweaking a bit the response of @lance-java, it looks something like:

```
    Task snapshotCheckingTask = project.tasks.create('snapshotCheckingTask', {
        doLast {
            def snapshots = new ArrayList()
            def projectConfigurations = project.configurations.findAll { true }

            projectConfigurations.each {
                if (it.isCanBeResolved()) {
                    it.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
                        if (it.moduleVersion.id.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
                            snapshots.add(it)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!snapshots.isEmpty()) {
                throw new GradleException("Please get rid of snapshots for following dependencies before releasing $snapshots")
            } else {
                throw new GradleException("Hah, no snapshots!")
            }
        }
    })
    project.tasks.release.dependsOn snapshotCheckingTask
```

cc @Eugene

P.S. However, this does not take into account .net dependencies

Comment: FYI in groovy you can write `it.isCanBeResolved()` as `it.canBeResolved`

Comment: Woah, thanks! Groovy's so much nicer in terms of readability compared to java

Comment: rewritten it a bit to a more functional style:
`def snapshots = project.configurations.findAll { it.canBeResolved }.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.flatten().findAll { it.moduleVersion.id.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT') }.unique()`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with using Gradle 7.2 and the modern Kotlin DSL:

```kotlin
tasks.register("releaseEnforcement") {
    group = "verification"
    description = "Check whether there are any SNAPSHOT dependencies."
    doLast {
        val violations = project.configurations
            .filter { it.name == "compileClasspath" || it.name == "runtimeClasspath" }
            .flatMap { configuration ->
                configuration.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts
                    .map { it.moduleVersion.id }
                    .filter { it.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT") }
            }
            .toSet()
        if (violations.isNotEmpty()) {
            error("Snapshot dependencies found:\n\n${violations.joinToString(separator = "\n")}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work in Gradle 8.2.1 and kotlin kmp 1.9, 
 Resolving dependency configuration 'compileClasspath' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.
     Instead, a resolvable ('canBeResolved=true') dependency configuration that extends 'compileClasspath' should be resolved.